# Putting the results of Case Statement in an Array for dumping it in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following piece of code I got there for copy a range of columns in another workbook. The issue is that I need to evaluate first some columns before copy the values. I'm using Case for this but I don't know passing the result, I was thinking in an array?

```
For i = LBound(arrayOrigen) To UBound(arrayOrigen)

  With Workbooks("facturas.xlsx").Worksheets("FACTURAS")

   lastrowOrig = Application.Max(2,Cells(.Rows.Count,arrayOrigen(i)).End(xlUp).Row)

    'For each cell in column D in source ,if is 0 put 0 in each cell target(destination) column(E)_'
   ' is not then put a formula in target column'
          If i = 3 Then
                   Set Column3 = .Range(.Cells(2, arrayOrigen(i)), .Cells(lastrowOrig, arrayOrigen(i)))

       For Each xCell In Column3
            Select Case True
            Case xCell.Value = 0
            result = 0
            Case Else
            result = "=RC[-1]*0.21"
          End Select
        **Sheets("RESUMEN").Range(arrayDestino(i) & lastrowDes).Resize(lastrowOrig - 2).Value =** _
         result
        'array is needed for store the diferents result for each cell and dumping in the destination
        'column all at once?'
     Next
       Else   'for the rest of columns copy entire column whith the same values'
        Sheets("RESUMEN").Range(arrayDestino(i) & lastrowDes).Resize(lastrowOrig - 2).Value = _
            .Range(.Cells(2, arrayOrigen(i)), .Cells(lastrowOrig, arrayOrigen(i))).Value

    End If
End With
Next
```

Now I'm not able to show the result of Case in the destination columns for each cell, instead of this, it dumps all the column every time that Case change

Comment: Why use a `Case` for just one non-default case? Just use `If ... Then ... Else`

Comment: Hi John tks , use case or if is not the problem, my problem is here ; Sheets("RESUMEN").Range(arrayDestino(i) & lastrowDes).Resize(lastrowOrig - 2).Value = "something" .                                 I need ; Case True then, cell (i, E) value= 0 , Case False then, cell (i+1,E).Value = "something", Case True, cell(i+2, E).Value=0 and so on ,where cells refer to column E in another sheet. Thank you very much

Comment: Please don't put code in comments. Use [edit] to add the additional info to your question.

Comment: sorry , my apologies